# sort -n the content of a bash space separated items array

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have this structure::

```
.
├── b withe spaces.py
├── c.py
├── lib.py
├── show.sh
└── sub
    └── a.py
```

I want this result::

```
$ bash ./show.sh
    9 lines c.py              => info from outside script
   17 lines a.py              => info from outside script
  300 lines b withe spaces.py => info from outside script
 1589 lines lib.py            => info from outside script
 1915 lines total             => info from outside script
```

It's easy to sort by `wc -l`::

```
$ wc -l *.py */*.py | sort -n
    9 c.py
   17 sub/a.py
  300 b withe spaces.py
 1589 lib.py
 1915 total
```

So my starting point was::

```
array=(
$(find ./ -name "*.py" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
  do
    llines=$(cat $file | wc -l)
    analyse='ouput analyse from some script'
    printf "%s =\t%25s => %s" $llines $file $analyse
  done
  ))

for item in ${array[@]}; do echo $item; done| sort -n
```

Comment: And what happened? Did this not work? Not get you the expected output? The actual question is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the array at all:

```
find ./ -name "*.py" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file ; do
    llines=$(wc -l < "$file")
    analyse='ouput analyse from some script'
    # ----- you missed quoting these ---->vvv
    printf "%s =\t%s => %s\n" "$llines" "$file" "$analyse"
done | sort -k1nr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do easier:

```
find . -name "*sh" -print0 | wc  --files0-from=- -l | sort -n | sed 's/\(^[0-9]\+\) \(.*\)/\1 lines \2 => info from outside script/'
```

In this case you will not execute `wc` for every file separately, which will save the time a bit.
Also `wc` will calculate total for you.